# How can I swap certain words in a string in Python? I want to be able to take a statement and be able to transform it into a question

Tags: python

I want to take the user's input - a statement - and phrase it like a question. For instance: 'you are a donkey' would go to 'why are you a donkey?' In order to do this I need to take the verb and the pronoun and make them swap places, while at the same time adding 'why' to the start. It's the former that I'm having trouble with. Assume you know the pronoun is 'you'. Is there  a clever way I can swap them?

Comment: You'll probably need to use the String.split() method to split your string into words. Once you have words, you can put them together with the + operator in any order you choose.

Comment: can you assume the verb is always in the same position in the input? if so, you could probably use split() method as mentioned and grab the verb based on the index position in the word list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) to do this:

```
'you are a donkey'.replace('you', 'why').replace('are', 'are you') + '?'
```

---

Note that the order of the `.replace` is important because the `replace` function will replace ***every*** occurrence of the first string with the second.

So if I had done this instead:

```
'you are a donkey'.replace('are', 'are you').replace('you', 'why') + '?'
```

you would notice, two `why`'s in there.

You can fix the second part by doing:

```
'you are a donkey'.replace('are', 'are you').replace('you', 'why', 1) + '?'
```

Note the extra argument (`1`) passed to the second `replace`, which tells the replace function that we only want to replace `you` with `why` once. So the second `you` is left in tact